# I want to fill the table with numbers from site parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to fill an Excel table with phone numbers from parsing the site. Please help to fill out the excel table with numbers only, without extra signs such as commas, parentheses, square brackets (they are like that)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

page = 0
page_count = input("Pages: ")
price = input("Price: ")

fn = 'example.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(fn)
ws = wb['data']


while page <= int(page_count):
    4
    

    def get_phone(id_):
        url1 = f"https://auto.ria.com/demo/bu/mainPage/rotator/item/{id_}?type=bu&langId=4"
        url2 = "https://auto.ria.com/users/phones/{id_}?hash={userSecureHash}"

        data = requests.get(url1).json()
        userSecureHash = data["userSecure"]["hash"]

        try:
            phone = requests.get(url2.format(id_=id_, userSecureHash=userSecureHash)).json()
        except:
            return data, []

        out = []
        for p in phone["phones"]:
            out.append(p["phoneFormatted"])

        return data, out


    url = "https://auto.ria.com/uk/search/?indexName=auto,order_auto,newauto_search&categories.main.id=1&country.import.usa.not=-1&price.USD.gte=" + str(price) +"&price.currency=1&abroad.not=0&custom.not=1&sellerType=1&page=" + str(page)
    print(price)
    print(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    all_data = []
    for a in soup.select("a.address"):
        id_ = a["href"].split("_")[-1].split(".")[0]
        data, phones = get_phone(id_)
        if not data:
            continue
        data.pop("userSecure")
        all_data.append({"phones": phones})

    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
    ws.append([str(df)])
    wb.save(fn)
    wb.close()
    print(df)
    page = page + 1
```

I'm new in web scraping, sorry if my question stupid

Comment: Look into [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to remove all non-digits from your data; something like `data = data.sub(r"\D", "")`

Comment: You should include examples of the numbers you need to process.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the data in the dataframe before writing to excel.
I included the line

```
df['phones'] = [' '.join(re.findall("\d+", item[0])) for item in df['phones']]
```

this changes
`(098) 439 76 31` to `098 439 76 31`.

If you don't want the spaces then changing the `' '.join` to `''.join` would give `0984397631` instead.
You are also writing the data as a list which is being added to the next available cell ('A1') with indexes. This is contributing to extraneous characters in your output data.
I've changed the write to Excel to use `ExcelWriter` so the data is written down the column, one cell per row. The writer used is set up to append to (i.e. not overwrite existing data) on the sheet and start at the next unused row + 1.
The Header (in this case 'phones') is written each time but can be disabled and another header used if desired.
I also changed the while loop to range so there is no need to increment the variable `'page'`. This variable is changed to expect input as an integer.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page_count = int(input("Pages: "))
price = input("Price: ")

for page in range(page_count+1):
    def get_phone(id_):
        url1 = f"https://auto.ria.com/demo/bu/mainPage/rotator/item/{id_}?type=bu&langId=4"
        url2 = "https://auto.ria.com/users/phones/{id_}?hash={userSecureHash}"

        data = requests.get(url1).json()
        userSecureHash = data["userSecure"]["hash"]

        try:
            phone = requests.get(url2.format(id_=id_, userSecureHash=userSecureHash)).json()
        except:
            return data, []

        out = []
        for p in phone["phones"]:
            out.append(p["phoneFormatted"])

        return data, out


    url = "https://auto.ria.com/uk/search/?indexName=auto,order_auto,newauto_search&categories.main.id=1&country.import.usa.not=-1&price.USD.gte=" + str(
        price) + "&price.currency=1&abroad.not=0&custom.not=1&sellerType=1&page=" + str(page)
    print(price)
    print(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    all_data = []
    for a in soup.select("a.address"):
        id_ = a["href"].split("_")[-1].split(".")[0]
        data, phones = get_phone(id_)
        if not data:
            continue
        data.pop("userSecure")
        all_data.append({"phones": phones})

    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
    ### Extract just numerals from the cell in the dataframe
    ### ' '.join retains spaces in the numbers 
    ### ''.join removes the spaces
    df['phones'] = [' '.join(re.findall("\d+", item[0])) for item in df['phones']]

    ### User ExcelWriter to create a writer in append mode
    ### The workbook 'example.xlsx' must exist. 
    with pd.ExcelWriter("example.xlsx",
                        mode="a",
                        engine="openpyxl",
                        if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:

        ### Add the dataframe to Excel on sheet 'data' and start at the next free row + 1
        ### Include the DF header but not the index number
        df.to_excel(writer,
                    sheet_name='data',
                    startrow=writer.sheets['data'].max_row + 1,
                    header=True,
                    index=False
                    )
    print(df)
```

Example of data output.
[image: Example data]